# Difference in behavior between generic and non-generic WeakReference

Tags: c#, .net-core, garbage-collection

I discovered something I did not expect in the behavior of generic WeakReference.

In my test, the instance of WeakReference are freed after a GC.Collect() call but not for generic WeakReference:

## Unit test case

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace NUnitTestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private const bool trackResurrection = false;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Default, true)]
        public void TestWeakReferenceWithObject(int generation, GCCollectionMode forced, bool blocking)
        {
            static WeakReference CreateWeakReference()
            {
                return new WeakReference(new object(), trackResurrection);
            }

            var x = CreateWeakReference();

            Assert.IsTrue(x.IsAlive);

            GC.Collect(generation, forced, blocking);

            Assert.IsFalse(x.IsAlive);
        }

        [TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
        public void TestWeakReferenceWithString(int generation, GCCollectionMode forced, bool blocking)
        {
            static WeakReference CreateWeakReference()
            {
                return new WeakReference(new string('a', 100), trackResurrection);
            }

            var x = CreateWeakReference();

            Assert.IsTrue(x.IsAlive);

            GC.Collect(generation, forced, blocking);

            Assert.IsFalse(x.IsAlive);
        }

        [TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
        public void TestGenericWeakReferenceWithObject(int generation, GCCollectionMode forced, bool blocking)
        {
            static WeakReference<object> CreateWeakReference()
            {
                return new WeakReference<object>(new object(), trackResurrection);
            }

            var x = CreateWeakReference();

            Assert.IsTrue(x.TryGetTarget(out var _));

            GC.Collect(generation, forced, blocking);

            Assert.IsFalse(x.TryGetTarget(out var _));
        }

        [TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
        public void TestGenericWeakReferenceWithString(int generation, GCCollectionMode forced, bool blocking)
        {
            static WeakReference<string> CreateWeakReference()
            {
                return new WeakReference<string>(new string('a', 100), trackResurrection);
            }

            var x = CreateWeakReference();

            Assert.IsTrue(x.TryGetTarget(out var _));

            GC.Collect(generation, forced, blocking);

            Assert.IsFalse(x.TryGetTarget(out var _));
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the documentation:

- [Weak References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references)
- [WeakReference Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference)
- [WeakReference<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference-1)

And the .NET Framework reference source code:

- [WeakReference Class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#985a18841b9c6087)
- [WeakReference<T> Class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#809df5135c2bec67)

But I can't find a reason to the different behave?

## Test parameters

### Passable parameters:

```
[TestCase(0, GCCollectionMode.Default, true)]
[TestCase(1, GCCollectionMode.Default, true)]
[TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Default, true)]
[TestCase(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
[TestCase(1, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
[TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
```

### Not passable parameters:

```
//[TestCase(0, GCCollectionMode.Optimized, true)]
//[TestCase(1, GCCollectionMode.Optimized, true)]
//[TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Optimized, true)]
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that any particular reference will be collected immediately after calling `GC.Collect()` so the runtime can behave differently for different types. See [my related question and its answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491193/weakreference-behaves-differently-between-net-framework-and-net-core)

Comment: Why do you think that the fact that one test uses generics has more relevance that the fact that one test uses `x.IsAlive` and the other `x.TryGetTarget(out var _)`?

Comment: Thank you @Holger you pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I got my generic weak reference test cases to pass, just by commenting out the first assert:

```
// Assert.IsTrue(x.TryGetTarget(out var _));
```

Or by moving the call to `WeakReference<T>.TryGetTarget(out T target)` it's own function:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace NUnitTestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private const bool trackResurrection = false;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }
       
        [TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
        public void TestGenericWeakReferenceWithObject(int generation, GCCollectionMode forced, bool blocking)
        {
            static WeakReference<object> CreateWeakReference()
            {
                return new WeakReference<object>(new object(), trackResurrection);
            }

            static bool IsAlive(WeakReference<object> weakReference)
            {
                return weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var _);
            }

            var x = CreateWeakReference();

            Assert.IsTrue(IsAlive(x));            

            GC.Collect(generation, forced, blocking);

            Assert.IsFalse(IsAlive(x));
        }

        [TestCase(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)]
        public void TestGenericWeakReferenceWithString(int generation, GCCollectionMode forced, bool blocking)
        {
            static WeakReference<string> CreateWeakReference()
            {
                return new WeakReference<string>(new string('a', 100), trackResurrection);
            }

            static bool IsAlive(WeakReference<string> weakReference)
            {
                return weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var _);
            }

            var x = CreateWeakReference();

            Assert.IsTrue(IsAlive(x));

            GC.Collect(generation, forced, blocking);

            Assert.IsFalse(IsAlive(x));
        }
    }
}
```

The discard variable in my call: `x.WeakReference(out var _)` must have keept a reference to the target of the weak reference.
Adding a variable scope did not affect the test case, it still failed:

```
{
    x.WeakReference(out var _)
}
```